# How to get .env variables in React Native with TypeScript and RN CLI?

Tags: react-native, environment-variables, react-native-cli

I'm working on a react native project with typescript and react native CLI (not expoCLI). These are the versions I have:

```
...
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.4",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-native": "0.68.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.12",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
    "react-native-dotenv": "3.4.7",
    "@types/react-native-dotenv": "0.2.0",
```

I have my .env file with some environment variables that I want to use inside my files. I follow the steps from the official documentation of https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv and adding the steps for typescript.

1. Create a .babelrc file with the plugins
2. add the "envName", "moduleName", "path"
3. My .env file has the following format `API_EXAMPLE=123`
4. I create te type folder and the env.d.ts folder with the declare module '@env'
5. I added the typeRoots on my tsconfig.json file *(this step is causing me errors with my unit test (types/jest package) if I delete this line everythings works again, but my env variables still doesn't work, so I'm going to find how to fix this error later)*

I tried a lot of stackoverflow's answers. For example:

- Changing the '@env' for 'react-native-dotenv'
- Make a yarn start --reset-cache
- Move my .env file to the root and inside the types (this steps with restarting my IDE and doing the yarn start --reset-cache)
- I tried with .babelrc and babel.config.js presets and settings
- Of course I delete my node_modules folder and install everything again

But after all of these steps I'm still having the following error on my console:

`unable to resolve module '@env' from 'src/../.../../../MyFile.js: @env could not be found within the project`

`Error: Unable to resolve module path from node_modules/react-native-dotenv`

`Module ../.../node_modules_@types/react-native-dotenv has no exported member API_EXAMPLE`

am I missing any steps?

Something else to clarify, this is the structure of my project:

```
projectFolder
--.github
--docs
--myApp (this folder contain the iOS and Android folder and files for execute my components)
--src
  |--- client
      |--- config
            |--- myApiConfigs.ts // this file contain the env variable I want to get from .env file (.env file is at .gitignore)
  |--- components // all of my react native components
-- .env //.env file are on my root folder, also tried at types folder
```

Answer (score 3):

doing some digging found [this blog](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-environment-variables-in-a-react-native-app-f2dd005d2457) that does the following:

.env file:

```
API_KEY=your_api_key_here
```

env.d.ts file:

```
declare module '@env' {
  export const API_KEY: string;
}
```

your component file:

```
import { API_KEY } from '@env';
```

but for this method each variable has to be added to the env types file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that the components where you try to use the environment variables are within the App.tsx
First add your configuration in babel.config:

---

```
plugins: [
      ["module:react-native-dotenv",{
        "envName": "APP_ENV",
        "moduleName": "@env",
        "path": ".env",
        "safe": false,
        "allowUndefined": true,
        "verbose": false
      }]
    ]
```

Create a types/env.d.ts folder and add this:

---

```
  declare module '@env' {
        export const CLIENT_SECRET: string;
      }
```

### Configure your typeRoots in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./src/types/env.d.ts"],
  }
}
```